# Sample size in survival analysis

Tags: survival, sample-size

[image]

My question, in this calculator (https://sample-size.net/sample-size-survival-analysis/) why is q1 is fixed to 0.7 thus q0 is fixed to 0.3.

Comment: q0 is determined by q1, so you only have to set one of the two. Seems like q1 is editable, so not actually fixed to 0.3

Comment: You can change q1 at that site, click another textbox after changing q1 and you'll see that q0 is 1-q1.  This is called the allocation ratio.